onTrack not getting called in flutter_webrtc package
I am trying to integrate a video calling feature in my app which would have flutter app on one end and angular web app on the other side (caller would be user with angular website and receiver would be on flutter mobile app) but the package available in flutter to integrate webrtc is not working correctly.
_makeConsume() async {
      ParticipantListAndChatsResponseModel participants = await _participantList( );
    participants.result?.participantsList.forEach((element) async {
      if (element.userId !=
          callerId) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
          "iceServers": []
        };

        RTCPeerConnection peerConnection =
            await createPeerConnection(configuration);

        RTCSessionDescription offer = await peerConnection.createOffer({});
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        print('Offer SDP: ${offer.sdp}');
        
        peerConnection.onAddStream = (MediaStream stream) {
          print('Add stream: ${stream.id}');
          _remoteRenderer.srcObject = stream;
        };
        peerConnection.onAddTrack = (MediaStream stream, MediaStreamTrack track) {
          print('Add track: ${track.id}');
          _remoteRenderer.srcObject = stream;
        };

        peerConnection.onRenegotiationNeeded = () {
          print('Renegotiation needed');
        };
        peerConnection.onTrack = (RTCTrackEvent event) {
          print('Track event: ${event.streams.length} streams');
          if (event.streams.isNotEmpty) {
            _remoteRenderer.srcObject = event.streams[0];
          }

          // print("ontrack");
          //     if (event.track.kind == 'video' && event.streams.isNotEmpty) {
          //     MediaStream _remoteStream = event.streams[0];
          //     _remoteRenderer.srcObject = _remoteStream;
          //     setState(() {});
          //   }
        };
        peerconnectionMap
            .addAll({"id": element.userId, "peerConnection": peerConnection});
        _consumeMedia(
            consumerId: element.userId ?? "",
            offer: offer,
            peerConnection: peerConnection);
      }
    });
  }

I am using my own socket (not socket.io) so other wrapper packages also are not feasible.
I am successful in sending the data back to the website but the main issue arises when I try to access the audio & video on flutter's end. I have tried inTrack, onRenegotiationNeeded, onAddStream and onAddTrack but nothing got called.
I want to fetch and show the media tracks coming from website to the flutter app.
